# Value Update of Bound ViewModel Property Fails

Tags: wpf, mvvm, custom-controls, mvvm-light, dependency-properties

I am trying to bind a custom control property to a property of its view model and its failing.

I have defined a Dependency property for settings StartDate and updated the PropertyChangeCallback method

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StartDateProperty = 
           DependencyProperty.Register(StartDatePropertyName,
                                       typeof(DateTime),
                                       typeof(CustomDateTimeControl),
                                       new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-7), 
                                                            OnStartDatePropertyChanged));

private static void OnStartDatePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, 
                                               DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
       DateTime dtNewValue = (DateTime)e.NewValue;
        if (dtNewValue != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            DateTimeControl dtCtrl = d as DateTimeControl;
            dtCtrl.StartDate = (DateTime)e.NewValue;
            dtCtrl.CoerceValue(StartDateProperty);
        }
 }
```

The `StartDate` property gets bound to its ViewModel's Start Date, since VM needs to perform some operation which would then be used to define the next available view for the custom control.

```
<Setter Property="StartDate" 
        Value="{Binding StartDate, 
                        Mode=OneWayToSource, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Also the DependencyProperty defined within is set from the mainWindow view

```
<CustomDateTimeLib:CustomDateTimeControl  StartDate="01/01/2000 00:00:00"  />
```

The binding updates the property in the view model only with the default value of the dependency property but not with the value being set with in the MainView as above even though the dependency property is getting updated with the value from MainView.

ViewModelLocator class

```
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
    static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CalendarViewModel>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Main property.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public CustomDateTimeLib:CustomDateTimeControl CalendarVM
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CustomDateTimeControl>();
            }
        }
}
```

App.Xaml

```
<Application x:Class="MvvmCustomTestApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CustomDateTimeLib.ViewModel"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         mc:Ignorable="d ignore">

<Application.Resources>
    <!--Global View Model Locator-->
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
</Application.Resources>
```

ApplyTemplate override method in CustomDateTimeControl class

```
 public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        CalendarViewModel vm = (CalendarViewModel)this.DataContext;
        vm.StartDate = this.StartDate;
```

}

Also defined a property change callback method for StartDate

Comment: Where is that `<Setter>` located, and what happens when you remove it? `OneWayToSource` tells the binding that it should only update the Source (your ViewModel) with the Target (your Control) value, so the binding will only ever work to transfer the value from the Control to your ViewModel, and not vice versa.

Comment: In order to make this work, the binding must be two-way.

Comment: The setter is present within the Generic.xaml. If i remove the <Setter> then there i no binding done hence my view model property isn't updated.  If i make it anything other than OneWayToSource my view model property isn't updated and rather has a DateTime default value. Also i wanted the source (viewModel) property to be updated only when the dependency property changes and not vice-versa.

Comment: Show how you bind the controls datacontext to the ViewModel.

Comment: I  am setting the Data context  explicitly on the Custom Control as DataContext="{Binding DateTimeCtrlVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"

Comment: What does the static resource `Locator` look like? The VM Xaml instantiation you have in your example is unnamed.

Comment: I have edited my original post and added the ViewModelLocator class and App.xaml class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a custom DP that you want to bind to a ViewModel property, however you also want to set the Default Value for this property from the View.

That is not an ideal setup for MVVM or for when you're using bindings. MVVM is supposed to have all the logic, including things like "default value for X" in the ViewModel layer, and the View layer is only used to provide the user with a visual way to interact with the ViewModel (data) layer.

So your solutions are either :

1. Set the default value in your ViewModel
2. Provide handling in your Dependency Property that if value == DateTime.Min, use a different default value
3. Use a Converter (for `DateTime`) or FallbackValue (for `DateTime?`) if you really want to have the View supply the default value
4. Use a second DP to define the default value that should be used
5. Add a Loaded event handler to the control to read the DataContext and set the Default Value

Option 1 is the best solution if you are using MVVM, since things like a custom DefaultValue should be set in the ViewModel, not the View.

Option 2 is best if this default value is specific to this UserControl, and will be the same anytime this control is used.

Options 3, 4, and 5 are for if you really do insist on setting the default value from the View layer for whatever reason. Which one to use depends on your situation.

---

Assuming you use #1,  I would expect your final XAML to look like this :

```
<!-- assumes DataContext is of type DateTimeCtrlVM via inheritance or direct binding -->
<CustomDateTimeLib:CustomDateTimeControl  StartDate="{Binding StartDate}"  />
```

That's it.

That `<Setter>` in your XAML code above is actually causing the following to happen :

- Control is created with default value of 1/1/2000
- Property is bound `OneWayToSource` to VM property, which means data will only flow from Target (Control) to Source (ViewModel), so the value of 1/1/2000 is getting persisted to your VM

So get rid of that Setter which binds the property as OneWayToSource, use the XAML binding shown above, and set the default value in the ViewModel and it should work.

Comment: I believe option #5 is most ideal for my problem as i want to bind the DP to property in ViewModel alongside which the user should be able to set the DP property from the. Although i do initialise the DP with a default value  as mentioned in code above. 

@Rachel I'm not sure how to get the loadedevent for the custom control (probably being a newbie), however i update the ViewModel property on ApplyTemplate overridden method (code added above) if it is the correct way I have approached this.

Comment: I have managed to find the LoadedEvent for the CustomControl and now update the VM's property from the Loaded event handler. Would you be able to explain as to whythe updating of the VM's property doesn't happen as expected and rather i have to updazte it using option #5 ?  

Also i tried retreiving the binding expresession within the loaded event handler and it returns as null.

Comment: @Dave23Rave I'm not too sure what your question is. Your binding was not updating the ViewModel property correctly because you had set it up as a OneWayToSource binding, which means the value only flows from the UserControl to the ViewModel, and never the other way around. I'm glad you found something that worked for you though :)